# Stop embeds from specific URLs

Tags: javascript, iframe, embed

Hello Just finishing up making a site which people can share content on, however I'm wanting to limit where people can embed videos from via iframe, is there a way to block specific sites from been embeddable ?

Comment: That would depend on the way the iframes are created but if it is all javascript, in theory, there could be a list of domains that could be checked before creating the iframe element. Would that apply in this case?

Comment: No unfortunately not, I overlooked how bad some of these video hosts are in terms of ads so i just went the usual root of embed code <iframe src="#"></iframe>

Comment: You can if you are able to set server side [X-Frame-Options](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/X-Frame-Options) headers